# React components like Thumbnail, LikeButton is not working

Tags: reactjs, video-thumbnails, react-video

I tried creating a react project with it's latest features <Thumbnail/>, <LikeButton/>. But I am getting this below error.

This is my code from React website (https://react.dev/).
The website does not say to install any additional thing.

````
const ReactVideo = (video) => {

  return (
    <div>
        <Thumbnail video = {video}/>
        <a href= {video.url}>
         <h3 className=''>{video.title}</h3>
         <p className=''>{video.description}</p>
        </a>
        <LikeButtoon video= {video}/>
    </div>
  )
}

export default ReactVideo```

getting this error below:

src\\components\\ReactVideo.jsx
Line 7:10:   'Thumbnail' is not defined    react/jsx-no-undef
Line 12:10:  'LikeButtoon' is not defined  react/jsx-no-undef
````

Comment: Did you have these two components? Did you import them？

Comment: I have these components. Did not import from outside